# $\langle Av,v\rangle=0, A\neq 0$ over the reals proof

Tags: linear-algebra

> Theorem: Let $V$ be as before. If $A$ is an operator such that $\langle Av,v\rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$ then $A=0$.

Proof: The left hand side of the polarization identity is equal to $0$ for all $v,w\in V$. Hence we obtain

$\langle Aw,v\rangle+\langle Av,w\rangle=0$

for all $v,w\in V$.Replace $v$ by $iv$. Then by the rules for the hermitian product, we obtain

$-i\langle Aw,v\rangle+i\langle Av,w\rangle=0$

whence

$-\langle Aw,v\rangle+\langle Av,w\rangle=0$

Adding this to the first relation obtained above yields

$2\langle Av,w\rangle=0$

whence $\langle Av,w\rangle=0$. Hence $A=0$,as was to be shown.$\blacksquare $ ***Linear Algebra, by Serge Lang.***

> Polarization identity:
>
> $\langle A(v+w),v+w\rangle-\langle A(v-w),v-w\rangle=2[\langle Av,w\rangle+\langle Aw,v\rangle]$
>
> for all $v,w\in V$, or also
>
> $\langle A(v+w),v+w\rangle- \langle A(v),v\rangle-\langle A(w),w\rangle=\langle Av,w\rangle+\langle Aw,v\rangle$

There is in the text book the following question regarding, the given theorem.

> Show that the analogue of theorem when $V$ is finite dimensional space over $\mathbb{R}$ is false. In other words, it may happen that $Av$ is perpendicular to $v$ for all $v\in V$ without $A$ being the zero map!

If I take $V=\mathbb{R}^2$

I can take A=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})&-\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})\\\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})&\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})\end{bmatrix}

Then: $\langle Av,v\rangle=0$ and $A\neq 0$,$v\neq0$

I can also see that the given proof does not work in the reals once $i\langle Aw,v\rangle+i\langle Av,w\rangle=2i\langle Av,w\rangle$

**Question**:

**1)** Is there a more general proof?

**2)** Is a more  general proof beyond the scope of the book?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by a more general proof? Do you mean when does $\langle Av,v\rangle=0$ identically imply $A=0$ and when doesn't it?

Comment: @anon Exactly that!

Comment: If $\langle-,-\rangle$ is a bilinear form, it never happens in characteristic-not-two since $\langle Av,v\rangle=0$ when $A$ is antisymmetric. In order to have a sesquilinear form you need a field with an automorphism of order two (like conjugation in $\Bbb C$) or the quaternions (which also has conjugation). Also, I just noticed you have your sines and cosines all mixed up incorrectly in your example of a rotation matrix.

Comment: What does "as before" mean? If $A$ is a real skew-symmetric matrix then $x^T Ax =0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$, even though $A$ is not $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can always consider the adjoint in the inner product and that solves it.

$<Av, v> = 0 \Rightarrow <Av, v> = <v, Av> \Rightarrow A$ is self adjoint, so it is diagonalizable over the reals. 
It is easy to prove the only posible eigenvalue is $0$, so you would have $A = Px0xP^{-1} $ which implies $A = 0$